# Trying to understand how a darlington transistor works

Tags: transistors

From my understanding the point of a darlington transistor is to take one voltage and boost it further than what a single transistor is capable of.

I can't understand how it is actually doing that, though. Looking at the diagram below, E (Emitter) would be ground and a voltage is applied to B (base). At a sufficient voltage, The transistor is "switched" and now the voltage that is C is now the base voltage of the second transistor. Then the second transistor can switch and C can flow to ground. Why is this second transistor in place? It seems like it could be eliminated.

[image]

Comment: to understand a Darlington, first you need to understand a regular, single BJT in "common-collector" configuration, a.k.a. a "voltage follower".  first understand the properly biased BJT as a **current amplifier**.

Comment: perhaps a good image for the "common-collector configuration" a.k.a. "voltage follower" is at http://www.dnatechindia.com/images/stories/Transistors/Bipolar_Transistor/Common_Collector_Transistor_Circuit.png .  the \$R_{in}\$ resistor is not necessary (could be a wire), but the issue is what are \$I_B\$ and \$I_E\$?  how are those two currents related if \$V_{CE}\$ is sufficiently large to keep the transistor out of saturation?  (and that battery voltage is mislabeled \$V_{CE}\$. the battery voltage is \$V_{CE} + V_{OUT}\$.)  get these concepts down first.  then the Darlington will make sense.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The key here is understanding that transistors (specifically BJTs) do not operate on voltages, but rather on currents.  There are a few voltages that matter, such as the voltage drop between the base and emitter, but as a general rule, it's the currents which matter for BJTs.

BJTs are current amplifiers.  The more current travels through the Base-Emitter path, the more current is permitted to pass through the Collector-Emitter path.  The relationship between these currents is well approximated by considering two regions.  The first is the "active" state, where the Collector-Emitter current is proportional to the Base-Emitter current.  The constant of proportionality of this relationship is called the "beta" of the transistor (often on the order of 100).  The second state, at higher currents, is known as the "saturation" state, where the Collector-Emitter current is relatively constant with respect to the Base-Emitter current.

Darlington pairs often appear in situations where high current amplification is needed.  They make "power BJTs" which are optimized to have a high saturation current, but it is very difficult to make such power BJTs with a high gain.  A darlington pair allows you to combine the best of both worlds.  The first transistor is a normal high gain BJT, multiplying the Base-Emitter current and permitting a large multiple of that to flow from Collector to Emitter.  The second transistor is a power BJT, which has a much lower gain, but better maximum currents.  The base of this BJT is fed by the entire combined current flowing through the smaller transistor, so the total current flowing from its Collector to its Emitter is even larger.

The above situation works well in both switching and amplifying modes for the transistor.  Indeed Darlington pairs are sometimes used to power motors in the switching mode.  If we only consider amplifying, a second major use case appears.  If we use two signal transistors (rather than one signal transistor and one power BJT), we can't handle the high currents, but we can have extremely high gains.  In theory, this pattern can be stacked as far as you like, each layer multiplying the total beta by the beta of that transistor.  Betas of 10,000 or 1,000,000 are achievable in these situations (limited by noise, of course).

Darlington pairs have some limits.  One limit is that their frequency response is limited by two transistors, not just one.  This constrains their high frequency use.  Another limit is that they are not very linear.  Specifically crafted amplifier circuits tend to provide far higher quality amplification.  However, they are small, simple, and tend to work.

Comment: Your explanation helps a lot. One thing I am wondering about is with the current of C flowing to the second transistor's base, then C should flow to the emitter. Since electricity flows in a path of least resistance, is the resistance lower on the Collector-Emitter path compared to Base-Emitter allowing the majority of the current to flow Collector-Emitter?

Comment: @Justin Resistance is not the best way to visualize the behavior of a transistor, because a transistor is not a resistive device.  I could double the voltage between the collector and the emitter, and the current would remain unchanged because the transistor doesn't operate on voltages that way.  I suppose you could try to calculate an "effective resistence," in which case you'd find the effective resistence on the second transistor is lower than the effective resistence of the first transistor.  However, you would not really be capturing anything meaningful about transistors.

Comment: In that example, the "effective resistence" of a transistor has to change if you vary the voltage across it, because the transistor will keep the current the same, regardless of voltage (not withstanding extreme cases, of course)

Comment: So how is it determined how much current is going to go from Base to Emitter vs Collector to Emitter on the second transistor since the base and collector are tied together.

Comment: @Justin That is answered by going much deeper into what a BJT actually is, as in how the silicon works.  I highly recommend looking online at how they work, but the absolute highest level view is that a BJT has a diode like region that prevents current from flowing from Collector to Emitter, and current going from Base to Emitter affects the diode like region in a way that makes it act less like a perfect diode, and lets current through. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9CrcRabTQ0s does a decent job of explaining it.

Comment: If you can keep your concepts a bit separated, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IcrBqCFLHIY actually explains transistors better, but they use a different type of transistor.  The transistor you have in your darlington pair is called a Bipolar Junction Transistor (BJT).  The one they describe in that video is for a Metal-Oxide Field Effect Transistor (MOSFET).  The concepts of doping and depletion regions and overcoming potentials are identical in BJT and MOSFETS, but BJTs are designed to overcome it as current flows from Base to Emitter, while MOSFETS actually overcome it with a...

Comment: ... voltage difference between base and emitter (with virtually no current flow).  If the first video doesn't capture it well enough for you, watch the second one, just be aware that you're going to have to reverse engineer the MOSFET process described in the second video and apply it to the shape of a BJT from the first video.  If it helps, remember that a BJT's structure is actually the same as a pair of diodes, back to back, and that may help you understand the current flows.

Answer (score 8):

> From my understanding the point of a darlington transistor is to take one voltage and boost it further than what a single transistor is capable of.

Incorrect. Bipolar junction transistors are **current-gain amplifiers**; for a given base current they allow a much larger collector current to flow. As such the first transistor amplifies its base current into a much larger collector current. This then becomes the base current for the second transistor which then further amplifies it, causing the overall current gain to easily reach over 500.

Comment: I see, so both the base and collector could be 5v, but the base could only be able to deliver 200ma while the collector could have 30amps for example. Right? 

Another question along with this is when the first transistor is "switched" the current from C can then switch the second transistor. Does this current then take the collector to emitter path and then close the transistor 2 again? Does this happen extremely quickly?

Comment: @Justin: There is a limit to how much current a transistor can conduct. Any current that the second transistor can't pass will be diverted to keeping it open instead.

Comment: @Justin, to understand this correctly, you have to be careful about the language you use to describe things.  this makes no sense: *"...so both the base and collector could be 5v..."*  5 volts relative to **what**?

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson 5V+ relative to E, with E being ground.
Ignacio, so does there have to be more current available to conduct through the transistor than the conductor is rated for to keep the switch closed.

Comment: so then we say that \$V_{CE}=5v\$.  are you saying that voltage at the base relative to the emitter is also 5 volts??  (that is \$V_{BE}=5v\$ ?)  i very much doubt that to be the case.

Comment: @Justin: A transistor is not a switch. A transistor *acting as* a switch is in a degenerate mode called "saturation" whereby the base current is high enough to allow more collector current through than is available.

Answer (score 4):

The point of a darlington is to use two transistors to look like one transistor with high gain.  In fact, the gain of the darlington is the product of the gain of the individual transistors.

Of course there is no free lunch.  In this case one downside is that the saturation voltage of this larger "transistor" is significantly more than that of a single BJT.  The response time, particularly the turn-off response time, will also be slower.

Comment: So the question remains: What is the ADVANTAGE of using a Darlington pair?

Comment: @LvW: As I said, the advantage is high gain.

Comment: High current gain, OK? But - why is this an advantage? Sorry for this silly question, but - for my opinion - it is important to realize the consequences.

Comment: @LvW: This is getting off topic for the question.  There are various reasons why high gain can be useful, depending on the circuit the transistor (or darlington) is used in.  For example, if you want to control something with a digital output that can source 10 mA, you can only control 100 mA if you have a gain of 10, 500 mA if you have a gain of 50, etc.  There are many applications where you have much less than 10 mA to start with, but might want to control 100s of mA or more.  The advantages of gain really should be obvious, since in most cases we use transistors because they have gain.

Comment: @O.Lathrop, For my opinion, the question "how does it work" includes also the point "why and where do we use it". And in this context, I think it is not off-topic to ask if a large current gain is desired (and why in some cases). And in your above comment you gave us some good examples.  I am sure , this can be of benefit to the questioner.

Comment: The switching time problem can be mitigated by [using resistors between base and emitter](https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/~hodges/DarlingtonCircuit.pdf) (for a Darlington transistor built from discrete transistors).

Answer (score 2):

The emitter current of first transistor is the base current of second transistor, which is again going to amplified by the factor of beta plus 1,  so what really is happening is that,

First, the base current is becoming emitter current, so it's getting amplified by beta plus one,

Secondly, this emitter current is becoming the base current of second transistor, so the second transistor again amplify it by the factor beta plus one, so total current amplification is square of the one stage amplification.

Comment: It's like if you have got uV(micro) converting it to mV then increasing the order of mV signal for example 10 uV to .01. mV then finally to 1 mV.

Answer (score 1):

Darlington pairs are commonly used for their high gain (hFE).

What you'll often see is a Darlington pair combined in a power transistor.

Power transistors (BJT) can usually cope with high collector currents, but have a low gain. By adding an extra transistor it gives you best of both worlds, high collector current at a low base current. But at the cost of higher saturation voltage.

Some other annoying properties come into play, but I think these are beyond the answer you are looking for. Things like parasitic capacitances, Miller effect, etc. Worth a question on its own.

Answer (score 0):

The point of a darlington transistor is to allow a weak signal to enable a small transistor, which in turn can enable a bigger transistor. It's similar to using a pre-amp or electric microphone amp before passing the signal to a power amp.

Answer (score 0):

I know that some participants of this thread will heavily disagree with me - but I think one should mention the BJT - from the physical point of view - is **NOT** a current-controlled device. Instead, the collector current is controlled and determined by the base-emitter voltage Vbe only! That is a proven fact.

On the other hand, of course it is true that there is a - more or less - fixed relation between Ic and Ib. And for many calculations (circuit analysis) we are allowed to treat the BJT as if it would be current-controlled (because of this fixed relationship between Ib and Ic). One simple example makes it clear: In a common emitter stage replace a BJT with a "current gain" of 100 with another BJT having a current gain of 200. For the same quiescent current Ic in both cases the voltage gain will be the same. The only parameter which has changed is the input resistance (because of the smaller base current).

And this is the main effect also for the Darlington combination. The current gain of the combination has increased (product of the beta values of the transistors) but the voltage gain remains about the same (for comparable DC conditions). The main advantage is the input resistance which has drastically decreased if compared with a single transistor.

It is true that the emitter current of the first BJT is identical to the base current of the second transistor but it is the base-emitter voltage - developped by this current - which controls the collector current of the second transistor.

Final remark: I consider it as important to know these physical facts in order to avoid misunderstandings and misinterpretation of formulas. Remember the gain formula for a simple gain state: **A=-gm*Rc**. The "current gain hie" plays no role, instead it is the transconductance gm=dIc/dVbe (slope of the function Ic=f(Vbe)) that determines the gain. Some people think: More current gain gives more voltage gain - but this is a severe  misconception!

**Barry Gilbert:** 
*BJT is a voltage-controlled current-source; the base current is purely incidental (it is best viewed as a „defect“)*

**EDIT:**
I`ve got the impression (disagreements and downvoting) that it could help to mention another reference (with more reputation that I have):

**Univ. of Berkeley:** 
*Ic is determined by the rate of electron injection from the emitter into the base, i.e., determined by VBE. An **undesirable** but **unavoidable side effect** of the application of VBE is a hole current flowing from the base, mostly into the emitter. This base (input) current, Ib,
is related to Ic by the common-emitter current gain,*

Comment: heavily disagree.  the FET is a VCIS, but the BJT is more accurately modeled as an ICIS.  both FET and BJT are non-linear devices but can be biased into a region where the behavior is *relatively* linear.  with resistors in the circuit any voltage can be turned into a current or vise-versa, but without resistors, the BJT is **most closely** modeled as an current-controlled current source, the Venerable Gilbert notwithstanding.

Comment: Yes - no surprise. I have expected such a disagreement, because I know that there are still many people who misinterpret the relation Ic=beta*Ib. Nevertheless, the BJT is voltage-controlled current source. Do you need references from US universities with best reputation? (I didn`t speak about how it is modeled but about the physical truth!).

Comment: Also the voltage gain for a Darlington CE stage is half the value for a single CE stage. Because now Vin is divide into two halves between two BJTs.

Comment: i am not misinterpreting the relation \$I_B \approx \beta I_C\$ which is a **very** good approximation when \$V_{CE}\$ is large enough to take the BJT out of saturation and (assuming NPN) \$I_B>0\$.  good enough that the "\$\approx\$" can be replaced with "=".  but you will **not** get a linear relationship between \$I_C\$ and \$V_{BE}\$.  sure, you can call it a VCIS but it's a non-linear control until you start surrounding the transistor with some resistors that will sorta linearize the thing.

Comment: probably a better model is $$ I_C = h_{fe}I_B + h_{oe}V_{CE} $$ for \$V_{CE} > V_{sat}\$ and \$I_B>0\$.  call it "\$h_{fe}\$" or "\$\beta\$".  i don't care.  $$  $$ too late to edit my previous comment but i reversed the positions of \$I_B\$ and \$I_C\$.  ooops.

Comment: @Robert B., I am not discussing linearity and I do not argue against Ic=beta*Ib. I am only saying that this relation must not considered as a control function. There is an exponential relation between Ic and Vbe - and it would be nice if it would be a linear relation. But I cannot change the physics. Vbe controls Ic - and we are using negative feedback if we want to linearize this behaviour. Your equation is correct, but it does not tell us that Ib would be the controlling quantity! That`s my point. Nothing else.

Comment: I wonder if the forum member who has downvoted my answer has one single counter argument. Please, be so fair and mention one single point where I am wrong! Thank you.

Comment: why a single point when you ignore many?

Comment: May I kindly ask you to give one example?

Comment: you don't listen. for some reason you think that all seminal electrical causes are EMF. but they're not. applying a voltage (as the cause) and measuring a current as an effect is not the only way things happen. you can also stuff a current into a device and measure the resulting voltage. **physically** it **is** about the charge. for every quantity of charge injected into the base from the emitter, because the emitter is so thin, a large portion (\$1-\frac{1}{\beta}\$) makes it to the collector junction without recombination. then that reverse-biased junction isn't so depleted of charge...

Comment: ... so for every unit of charge that is injected into the base, this portion (\$1-\frac{1}{\beta}\$) is drawn over the CB junction by a very high EMF (\$V_{CB}\$).  a smaller portion (\$\frac{1}{\beta}\$) of that charge recombines in the base is is drawn off in the base terminal.  and charge moving in a given slice of time is **current**.

Comment: lastly, we **are** talking about linear models.  like this: http://cp.literature.agilent.com/litweb/pdf/ads2008/ccsrc/3121445/ccsrc-2-2-01.gif .  that's how we analyze circuits and make amplifiers.  without being surrounded by resistors (which convert voltages into currents and vise-versa), the BJT is **most closely** modeled as a **current-controlled current source**.  to deny that is pedagogically useless.  in fact it's pedagogically harmful.

Comment: i meant to say in my comment 8 minutes ago "because the **base** is so thin, a large portion..."

Comment: Wow, and that is an exampe to show that I - and leading US universities - are wrong in saying that the BJT is voltage-controlled?

Comment: @LvW [argument from authority](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument_from_authority) isn't gonna cut it.  the holes and the electrons don't care.  the BJT is most closely modeled as a current-controlled current source, because it is just as fundamental to drive the base of the BJT with a given current as it is to drive the base-emitter junction with a given voltage.  the behavior of the collector current is most closely linearly related to the base current than to the base-emitter voltage.  someone just starting to understand the darlington isn't gonna do it with Eber-Molls equations.

Comment: Robert-just one simple technical question: It is a proven fact that the transfer characteristics of a simple diff. pair (BJT) follows a tanh function. Can you derive this function without using the e-function of voltage-control?

Comment: @LvW, probably not.  and if the Darlingtons were the front-end of a diff amp **and** you wanted to derive the \$\tanh()\$ characteristic (which is quite linear for small differential input), you need to do that from the fundamental V-I equations.  my point in taking issue with your initial claim (BJT as VCIS) in the context of this question (which is simply about what a darlington pair does and it works) is, at best, pedagogically useless. and it's unnecessary.  when describing V-I characteristics, it's just a fundamental to define I as it is to define V.  particularly for a low input-Z port.

Comment: OK - I can agree to this (as far as the context of this question is concerned). Thank you.